# How to represent difference between same fields from two different and simultaneous searches in a table format in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have to represent difference of fields from two different searches on same index with different tokens.

The first search will be as below:

```
index = main sourcetype=regression1 |eval field1 = seed
```

and the second is following :

```
index = main sourcetype=regression2 |eval field2 = seed
```

I tried following queries but not able to achieve my requirement:

```
 |multisearch [index = main sourcetype=regression1 |eval field1 = seed] 
 [ index = main sourcetype=regression2 |eval field2 = seed] 
 |eval field3 = field2 - field1 
 |table field1,field2,field3
```

also with if condition:

```
 index = main sourcetype=regression1 AND index = main sourcetype=regression2 
 |eval field1 = seed if(index = "main" AND sourcetype="regression1")
 |eval field2 = seed if(index = "main" AND sourcetype="regression2")
 |eval field3 = field2 - field1 
 |table field1, field2, field3
```

Any help will be very useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only assigning `field1` is the sourcetype is "regression1" and `field2` if sourcetype is "regression2". You can never subtract those, since they do not exists in the same events.

First you need to make sure to populate them everywhere like this:

```
index=main sourcetype IN(regression2,regression1)
| eval field1=if(match(sourcetype,"1$"),seed,0)
| eval field2=if(match(sourcetype,"2$"),seed,0)
| eval field3=field2-field1
| table field1 field2 field3
```

Comment: Thanks. However this is not working, only for field2 data is coming, for field1 it it giving 0 meaning if condition not matching. However if I keep only regression2 or regression1 in the IN, then the eval expression is getting correct value from the if match.

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast - where is 'seed' coming from?

Comment: It is coming from main only. Now I tried with a slightly different regex now it 's working. But the data for field1 and fied2 are now coming in separate rows. Not in same row which I want.

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast - please be more specific. Based on your initial sample, what I posted should work :)

Comment: it is working with your code. My real time scenario was slightly different hence initially I had some issues which I have fixed. It has nothing to do with your solution. Thanks much :)